# how to display image from oracle to table using php

Tags: php, html, oracle

what i have done ,
i store the image name in my oracle table food_item in the attribute photo;
now i want to display the image into a table called food_item table using php 
here is my code, i use $num to indicate the 9 the column in the table ,,i am sure that image name is saved correctly into oracle table
this the path E:\Xamp\htdocs where the photos are saved

but when i run the php file image is not showing

```
<?php 
    //File: anyco.php
    require('anyco_ui.inc.php');
    //Create a database connection
    $conn = oci_connect('system','123','localhost/orcl');
    ui_print_header('FoodItemList');




    //ui_print_footer(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

    function do_query($conn, $query)
    {
            $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            $r = oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);
            print '<table border="1">';
            print '<tr>';
            print '<td>Food_ID<td>Food_Name<td>Price(tk)<td>Dvailable_day<td>Avaliable_time<td>Discount<td>Dis_start date<td>Dis_finish date<td>photo';
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
            {
                print '<tr>';
                $num=0;
                foreach ($row as $item) 
                {                  
                    $num++;
                    if($num==9)

                        echo "<td><img src ='htmlentities($item)' <td>";
                    else
                        print '<td>'.($item!== null ? htmlentities($item) : '&nbsp;').'</td>';

                }

                print '</tr>';
           }

       print '</table>';
    }

?>
<html>
<style>
body
{
background:orange;
}
</style>
<body <body style="background-color:#FF0066"
text="green">

<br><br>
<form method="post">
<?php do_query($conn, 'SELECT Fooditem_ID,Food_item_name,price,day_available,time_available,discount_percentage,start_date,deadline,photo FROM Food_Item'); ?>
<br><br><a href="next.php">back</a></p>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hint: Look at the syntax highlighting. Do you think `htmlentities()` will be executed or will it just echo `src='htmlentities..`?

Comment: plz give me the syntax

Comment: ok i got it nd it works thnx